# CouchDB Read Configuration from design document

Tags: couchdb

I would like to store a value in the config file and look it up in the design document for comparing against update values. I'm sure I have seen this but, for the life of me, I can't seem to remember how to do this.

*UPDATE*

I realize (after the first answer) that there was more than one way to interpret my question. Hopefully this example clears it up a little. Given a configuration:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/_config/shared/token -d '"0123456789"'
```

I then want to be able to look it up in my design document

```
{
  "_id": "_design/loadsecrets",
  "validate_doc_update": {
    "test": function (newDoc,oldDoc) { 
       if (newDoc.supersecret != magicobject.config.shared.token){
         throw({unauthorized:"You don't know the super secret"});
       } 
    }
  }
}
```

It's the abilitly to do something like the `magicobject.config.shared.token` that I am looking for.

*UPDATE 2*

Another potentially useful (contrived) scenario

```
curl -X PUT http://trustedemployee:5984/_config/eventlogger/detaillevel -d '"0"'
curl -X PUT http://employee:5984/_config/eventlogger/detaillevel -d '"2"'
curl -X PUT http://vicepresident:5984/_config/eventlogger/detaillevel -d '"10"'
```

Then on devices tracking employee behaviour:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/logger",
  "updates": {
    "logger": function (doc,req) { 
      if (!doc) {
        doc = {_id:req.id};
      }
      if(req.level < magicobject.config.eventlogger.detaillevel ){
        doc.details = req.details;
      }
      return [doc, req.details];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a follow-up to my last answer with more general info:

There is no general way to use configuration, because CouchDB is designed with scalability, stability and predictability in mind. It has been designed using many principles of [functional programming](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-rise-and-fall-and-rise-of-functional-programming-composable-software-c2d91b424c8c) and [pure functions](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-pure-function-d1c076bec976), avoiding side effects as much as possible. This is a Good Thing™.

However, each type of function has additional parameters that you can use, depending on the context the function is called with:

- [**show**](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#show-functions), [**list**](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#list-functions), [**update**](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#update-functions) and [**filter**](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#filter-functions) functions are executed for each request, so they get the request object. Here you have the `req.secObj` and `req.userCtx` to (ab)use for common configuration. Also, AFAIK the `this` keyword is set to the current design document, so you can use the design doc to get common configuration (at least up to CouchDB 1.6 it worked).
- [**view**](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#view-functions) functions (map, reduce) don't have additional parameters, because the results of a view are written to disk and reused in subsequent calls. map functions *must* be pure (so don't use e.g. `Math.random()`). For shared configuration across view functions *within a single design doc* you can use CommonJS `require()`, but only [within the `views.lib` key](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/query-server/javascript.html#commonjs-modules).
- [**validate doc update**](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions) functions are not necessarily executed within a user-triggered http request (they are called before each write, which might not be triggered only via http). So they have the `userCtx` and `secObj` added as separate parameters in their function signature.

So to sum up, you can use the following places for configuration:

- `userCtx` for user-specific config. Use a special role (e.g. with a prefix) for storing small config bits. For example [superLogin](https://github.com/colinskow/superlogin) does this.
- `secObj` for database-wide config. Use a special member name for small bits (as you should normally use roles instead of explicit user names, `secObj.members.names` or `secObj.admins.names` is a good place).
- the design doc itself for design-doc-wide config. Best use the `this.views.lib.config` for this, as you can also read this key from within views. But keep in mind that all views are invalidated as soon as you change this key. So if the view results will stay the same no matter what the config values are, it might be better to use a `this.config` key.

Hope this helps! I can also add examples if you wish.

Comment: "There is no general way to use configuration" that is the answer I was looking for (just not the one I wanted). That is a nice summary of what *is* available though.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I know what you're talking about, and if I'm right then what you  are asking for is no longer possible. (at least in v1.6 and v2.0, I'm not sure when this feature was removed)

There was a lesser-known trick that allowed a view/show/list/validation/etc function to access the parent design document as `this` in your function. For example:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/hello-world",
  "config": {
    "PI": 3.14
  },
  "views": {
    "test": {
      "map": "function (doc) { emit(this.config.PI); })"
    }
  }
}
```

This was a *really* crazy idea, and I imagine it was removed because it created a circular dependency between the design document and the code of the view that made the process of invalidating/rebuilding a view index a very tricky affair.

I remember using this trick at some point in the distant past, but the feature is definitely gone now. (and likely to never return)

Comment: Not what I meant, but that was going to be my workaround :(

Comment: Are you talking about using [CommonJS modules](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/query-server/javascript.html#commonjs-modules) then?

Comment: No, I'm looking to access the server's configuration. The more I think about this, the more I think it isn't possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

For your special use-case (validating a document with a secret token), there *might* be a workaround, but I'm not sure if the token might leak in some place. It all depends what your security requirements are.

You could abuse the 4th parameter to validate_doc_update, the securityObject (see [the CouchDB docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions)) to store the secret token as the first admin name:

```
{
  "test": "function (newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx, secObj) {
    var token = secObj.admins.names[0];
    if (newDoc.supersecret != token) {
      throw({unauthorized:"You don't know the super secret"});
    }
  }"
}
```

So if you set the db's security object to `{admins: {names: ["s3cr3t-t0k3n"], roles: ["_admin"]}}`, you have to pass 's3cr3t-t0k3n' as the doc's supersecret property.

This is obviously a dirty hack, but as far as I remember, the security object may only be read or modified by admins, you wouldn't immediately leak your token to the public. But consider adding a separate layer between the CouchDB and your caller if you need "real" security.

Comment: A nice solution, unfortunately only accessible from the validate_doc_update. (You may even notice that my example is invalid, that's because I rewrote it from an update handler.)

Comment: Depending on what your use case is, there are also other solutions you can use. If you provide more detailed information, I can help you.

Comment: Really, I'm looking for a general way to store re-usable configuration values for my design documents (as described by Dominic), but I was hoping for the values to a) be independant of the design document itself b) be reusable across documents